# PHP read file using fopen on windows

Tags: php

What's problem in this code :

```
$handle = fopen("c:\DIGIPROG\welcome.txt", "rt");
```

OR

Something problem with another?

I set DIGIPROG folder Full access to everyone but still found error like this :

```
Warning: fopen(c:\DIGIPROG\welcome.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\digi\test.php on line 1
```

Then, I tried to open the address directly from run : c:\DIGIPROG\welcome.txt
and it's opened.

My question, is it possible to read using fopen in folder on windows OS ?
Please help with example :)

Thanks

Comment: Escape the escape characters: `"c:\\DIGIPROG\\welcome.txt"` or use forward slashes: `"c:/DIGIPROG/welcome.txt"`.

Comment: @Jack I tried, but error still same like before

Comment: Well, then, the file is simply not there or you're dealing with some funky Unicode issues :)

Comment: Please please read error.... I am pretty sure "c:\DIGIPROG\welcome.txt" doesn't exists...

Comment: Wait... example the server xampp in IP : 192.168.1.1 and I open the web address on IP 192.168.1.2, is it OK? Because when I open it in server xampp (with exist folder and file) it's OK. What I want is, open the web address in another IP then can accessed that PC folder and file in C drive

Comment: A php server cannot access the C drive of anybody who requests a page, that would be the most ridiculous thing ever. ^ assuming that is what you meant...

Answer (score 0):

thats surely because the USER running your php executable has no read access to that path.

1. is a webservice running the php.exe process ? if so, what is the user (use your taskbar) surely it is SYSTEM (by default).
2. are you running the php script by hand ? then, your user (that used when you login on windows) must have READ permissions in that directory.

in both cases, right click the folder, go to security tab, add read permission to the SYSTEM user (or your user).  To make a test only tell ALL USERS have read permission, remember to remove this entry later.